# How to get Date Month values in linux date command as integers to work on

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to convert date and month as integers.

for example.

if the current date as per the command "**Date +%m-%d-%y**" output, is this
**09-11-17**
Then I am storing

```
cur_day=`date +%d`
cur_month=`date +%m`
```

the $cur_day will give me **11** and $cur_month will give me **09**.

I want to do some operations on the month as 09. like i want to print all the numbers up to 09.

```
like this 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09
```

Same way I want to display all the numbers up to cur_day

```
like 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11
```

Please tell me how can i do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For months:

```
$ printf ',%02d' $(seq 1 $(date +%m)) | sed 's/,/like this /; s/$/\n/'
like this 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09
```

For days:

```
$ printf ',%02d' $(seq 1 $(date +%d)) | sed 's/,/like /; s/$/\n/'
like 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11
```

`printf` will print according to a format.  In this case, the format `,%02d` formats the numbers with commas and leading zeros.

The sed command puts the string you want at the beginning of the line and adds a newline at the end.

Comment: Thanks John1024.. Can we take the same number in for loop input like.. for ((i=1;i<=$cur_day;i++)); do echo $i;done.... like this?

Comment: @Subhantech You're welcome.  And, yes, your `for` loop works, printing one number per line.